# matlab show change in 3D data

Tags: matlab, visualization

What I would like to do is visualise the change in 3 dimensional data. For example i have two arrays:

before:

```
x y z
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

after:

```
x y z
2 2 3
5 5 6
8 8 9
```

I would like for the plot to be 3D scatter data like the folowing:

[image]

I know about quiver3 which plots norms but i am not sure how to do it from just 2 lists of X, Y, Z points.

The actual data will be much more complex.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Arrow.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/278-arrow-m) is available from the Matlab File Exchange that makes drawing arrows really easy:

```
>> A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
>> B = [2 2 3; 5 5 6; 8 8 9];

>> hold on
>> scatter3(A(:,1), A(:,2), A(:,3))
>> scatter3(B(:,1), B(:,2), B(:,3))
>> arrow(A, B)
```

Otherwise, take a look at other answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962332/how-to-draw-vectors-physical-2d-3d-vectors-in-matlab).