# 3D Vector Plot Gone Wrong

Tags: vector, 3d, octave

I have written a script in Octave below based off of a post:
[How to draw vectors (physical 2D/3D vectors) in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962332/how-to-draw-vectors-physical-2d-3d-vectors-in-matlab)

I have the following code in Octave and I get the error
' "vector" undefined near line 3 column 1'

Can anyone help me? I have written a few other *.m files for Octave with no problem and now I am stuck.

```matlab
a = [0 0 1];   %# Vector 1  
b = [0.894 0 0.447];   %# Vector 2
c = [0.276 0.851 0.447];   %# Vector 3
d = [-0.724 0.526 0.447];   %# Vector 4
e = [-0.724 -0.526 0.447];   %# Vector 5
f = [0.276 -0.851 0.447];   %# Vector 6 
g = [0.724 0.526 -0.447];   %# Vector 7 
h = [-0.276 0.851 -0.447];   %# Vector 8    
i = [-0.894 0 -0.447];   %# Vector 9    
j = [-0.276 -0.851 -0.447]   %# Vector 10   
k = [0.724 -0.526 -0.447];   %# Vector 11   
l = [0 0 -1];   %# Vector 12

starts = zeros(3,3);
ends = [a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h;i;j;k;l];

quiver3(starts(:,1), starts(:,2), starts(:,3), starts(:,4), starts(:,5),
        starts(:,6), starts(:,7), starts(:,8), starts(:,9), starts(:,10),
        starts(:,11), starts(:,12), ends(:,1), ends(:,2), ends(:,3),
        ends(:,4), ends(:,5), ends(:,6), ends(:,7), ends(:,8), ends(:,9),
        ends(:,10), ends(:,11), ends(:,12), 0)

axis equal
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because `starts` is of size 3x3 and you are indexing it up to 12 on the column index. The error message I get is:

```
error: A(I,J): column index out of bounds; value 4 out of bound 3
```